# Pin-priority and updating system

Tags: apt

According to `man apt_preferences`:

> `0 < P <=100`
>
> causes a version to be installed only if there is no installed version of the package.

Will a application that does not exist in any other package than the one with pin-priority of 50, be updated after being installed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you assign a pin-priority of 50 to a package, it will be installable, but once installed it won’t be automatically upgradeable.

The reason is that the installed version of any package is assigned priority 100. Since this is greater than 50, any version pinned to 50 won’t be a candidate.

Such packages can be upgraded by specifying the desired release:

```
sudo apt -t bullseye upgrade
```